# asp.net でログイン画面を作りたい

Tags: c#, asp.net

ログイン画面のレイアウトは完成しています。aspnetでは、あまりコードを書くようなことはせず、Identityなどをつかって作成することができるなどの情報は入手したのですが、実際にどのように手順を踏んでやればよいかわからないので質問させていただきました。環境はvs2017　webforms　framework 4.6.1　です。
イメージは、未入力時に未入力アラートを出す、IDかPWのどちらかか及び両方が間違っていたら、アラートを出すフォームを作りたいと思っています。

Comment: 検索するとこんなのが見つかって参考になりそうですが。[How To Create Login Page In ASP.NET Web Application Using C# And SQL Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-login-page-in-asp-net-web-application-using-c-sharp-and-sql-server/), [Simple Login Form in ASP.Net Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/simple-login-form-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp/), [Simple login form example in asp.net Check Username and Password availability in database](https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/how-to-create-simple-login-form-using.html)

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/345200 マルチポストだよね？